# Python Pandas: Groupby and Apply multi-column operation

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation, multiple-columns

df1 is DataFrame with 4 columns.

I want  to created a new DataFrame (df2) by grouping df1 with Column 'A' with multi-column operation on column 'C' and 'D'

Column 'AA' = mean(C)+mean(D)

Column 'BB' = std(D)

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three','two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
    'C' : np.random.randn(8), 
    'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

   A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  1.652675 -1.983378
1  bar    one  0.926656 -0.598756
2  foo    two  0.131381  0.604803
3  bar  three -0.436376 -1.186363
4  foo    two  0.487161 -0.650876
5  bar    two  0.358007  0.249967
6  foo    one -1.150428  2.275528
7  foo  three  0.202677 -1.408699

def fun1(gg): # this does not work
    return pd.DataFrame({'AA':C.mean()+gg.C.std(), 'BB':gg.C.std()})


dg1 = df1.groupby('A')
df2 = dg1.apply(fun1)
```

This does not work. It seems like aggregation() only works for Series and multi-column operation is not possible.
And apply() only produce Series output with multi-column operation.
Is there any other way to produce multi-column output (DataFrame) with multi-column operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a typo in your `f` function? Should `AA` be `C.mean() + C.std()` or `C.mean() + D.mean()`

In this first case, `AA` = `C.mean() + C.std()`,

```
In [91]: df = df1.groupby('A').agg({'C': lambda x: x.mean() + x.std(),
                                    'D': lambda x  x.std()})

In [92]: df
Out[92]: 
            C         D
A                      
bar  1.255506  0.588981
foo  1.775945  0.442724
```

For the second one `C.mean() + D.mean()`, things aren't quite as nice. When you give the `.agg` function on groupby objects a dict, I don't think there's a way to get values from two columns.

```
In [108]: g = df1.groupby('A')

In [109]: df = pd.DataFrame({"AA": g.mean()['C'] + g.mean()['D'], "BB": g.std()['D']})

In [110]: df
Out[110]: 
           AA        BB
A                      
bar  0.532263  0.721351
foo  0.427608  0.494980
```

You may want to assign g.mean() and g.std() to temporary variables to avoid calculating them twice.